# Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token

Tags: c++

I honestly have no idea why this is happening. I checked, double-checked, and triple-checked curly braces, semicolons, moved constructors around, etc. and it still gives me this error.

Relevant code follows.

BinTree.h

```
#ifndef _BINTREE_H
#define _BINTREE_H

class BinTree
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        float data;
        Node *n[2];
    };
    Node *r;

    Node* make( float );

public:
    BinTree();
    BinTree( float );
    ~BinTree();

    void add( float );
    void remove( float );

    bool has( float );
    Node* find( float );
};

#endif
```

And BinTree.cpp

```
#include "BinTree.h"

BinTree::BinTree()
{
    r = make( -1 );
}

Node* BinTree::make( float d )
{
    Node* t = new Node;
    t->data = d;
    t->n[0] = NULL;
    t->n[1] = NULL;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you (a) copied in the complete error message, (b) indicated where in the code it occurs and (c) which compiler on which platform you're using.

Comment: It should be mentioned that your include guards aren't safe. A name beginning with an underscore than a capital letter is reserved for the compiler. You should do something like change `_BINTREE_H` to `BINTREE_H`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because on the line:

```
Node* BinTree::make( float d )
```

the type `Node` is a member of `class BinTree`.

Make it:

```
BinTree::Node* BinTree::make( float d )
```

Comment: Geez, did NOT know you had to do that. Many thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: It's tricky.  Interestingly, you do NOT have to qualify *parameters* with `BinTree::` -- only return types.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: the parameter-declaration-clause (and everything that's part of a function definition after the identifier that names the function) is in the 'potential scope of a declaration' for a 'class definition' (3.3.6/5 "Class scope"). In other words, all members of a class are in scope for member function definitions *after* the name of the function. So the return type doesn't get the benefit of being in class scope; it comes too early. C++ 0x has a new *trailing-return-type* syntax that lets you work around this, but it's really being added for deducing return types in templates.