# Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token Templated linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

My problem is really similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271390/expected-constructor-destructor-or-type-conversion-before-token). However, my implementation differs in that I'm using a templated linked-list

Here's where I'm getting errors (second line). The purpose of this function is to return a pointer to a node at the k-th location in the list

```
template <class T>
List<T>::ListNode* List<T>::find(int k)
{
    ListNode * curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL && k > 0) {
        curr = curr->next;
        k--;
    }

    return curr;
}
```

And this is what my list looks like (made up of nodes, which store arbitrary data of type T)

```
template <class T>
class List
{
    private:
    class ListNode
    {
        public:
        ListNode();
        ListNode(T const & ndata);

        ListNode * next;
        ListNode * prev;
        const T data; 
    };
```

Essentially this is the same question as the one I linked to, except that my list is templated.  So, after making the changes that fixed the other problem, my code still throws errors. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: You may want to include a description of the errors here as well.

Comment: Post the error and the exact line that you get it on.

Comment: You may want to use `std::list` instead of writing your own.  Your issue is one reason not to build your own:  the STL version is already tested.

Comment: You probably don't want data to be `const`.  You probably _do_ want `find` to be `const`.  (`List<T>::find(int k) const`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `typename` keyword:

```
template <class T>
typename List<T>::ListNode* List<T>::find(int k)
{
    ...
}
```

This lets the compiler know that `ListNode` is a type. It is needed whenever you have a dependent name (i.e. one which depends on a template parameter) which is a type.